# Алфавит языка программирования Java и Unicode

Tags: java, unicode, char, символы, грамматика

Мне кажется, что этот вопрос скорее из плоскости философии, но всё равно было бы неплохо разобраться. Итак, начну немного издалека, чтобы была понятна суть. Абсолютно любой язык программирования, в том числе и упомянутый в заголовке Java, является формой формального языка, который предназначен для записи компьютерных программ. Если говорить грубо, то формальный язык представляет собой математическую модель реального языка и содержит набор правил, которые позволяют определить язык, в том числе множество грамматик (в иерархии Хомского выделено 4 типа формальных грамматик), предназначенных для этих целей. Разумеется, что каждый язык имеет свой алфавит, так что формальные языки не выпадают из этого правила и также подразумевают наличие некоторого множества атомарных символов, которые позволят выстраивать слова на этом языке и выступать в качестве основы терминальных символов. Запомним этот момент, так как он нам ещё пригодится.

Как только мы начинаем знакомиться с JLS, то уже во второй главе узнаём о том, что Java относится к формальным языкам с контекстно-свободной грамматикой, что и не сильно удивляет, так как подавляющее большинство языков программирования описывается именно при помощи этого типа формальной грамматики. Какую основную мысль мы можем выделить из этого для себя? Если мы имеем дело с КС-грамматикой, то любую лексическую и синтаксическую структуру, мы будем описывать при помощи продукций, в левой части которых всегда будет находиться исключительно один нетерминальный символ (отсутствует окружающий его контекст), который может быть выражен через некоторое сочетание, как терминальных, так и нетерминальных символов, начиная с целевого символа.

Чтобы понять, чем ограничен алфавит языка программирования Java, давайте обратим внимание на одну из продукций, которая представлена в разделе `3.3. Unicode Escapes`. Приведу её полностью.

```
UnicodeInputCharacter:
  UnicodeEscape
  RawInputCharacter
UnicodeEscape:
  \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
UnicodeMarker:
  u {u}
HexDigit:
  (one of)
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F
RawInputCharacter:
  any Unicode character
```

Здесь нас больше всего интересует фраза `any Unicode character`, которая чётко даёт понять, что в качестве необработанного входного символа может выступать совершенно любой символ стандарта Unicode. И вот тут напрашивается вопрос. Любой Unicode-символ? Что именно подразумевалось в данном контексте под словом «любой»? Все символы, которые описаны стандартом по состоянию на сегодняшний день? Или же всё то кодовое пространство, которое описывается в общем и целом?

Здесь ведь вот какой интересный момент возникает. Я даже не буду брать пробельные символы (в том числе ограничители строк) и комментарии, они всё равно относятся к разряду незначащих и полностью игнорируются компилятором. Возьмём хотя бы лексические токены, которые составляют основу любой Java-программы. С ключевыми словами, операторами и разделителями всё понятно, их набор заранее определён и фиксирован спецификацией языка. А сколько тех же Unicode-символов можно использовать при составлении корректных идентификаторов? Выяснить это достаточно легко. Воспользовался методами `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(codepoint)` и `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(codepoint)`, которые поместил в тело цикла и прогнал через них все возможные значения кодовых позиций. Итак, многих это может удивить, но в качестве начального символа нашего Java-идентификатора мы можем использовать 125,951 различный Unicode-символ! И это только результат работы метода `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(codepoint)`. К примеру, тот же `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(codepoint)`, сообщает нам, что частью корректного Java-идентификатора может быть уже 129,053 символа. Во всяком случае, эта информация достоверна для версии Java SE 14, которая официально поддерживает Unicode 12.1. Такое огромное количество связано с тем, что в составе идентификатора могут быть фактически любые буквы национальных алфавитов, куча иероглифов, валютные символы, форматирующие и даже управляющие, не говоря уже о многих других символах, типа различных разновидностей пробелов и других специальных символов (к примеру, `U+2060` WORD JOINER, `U+2061` FUNCTION APPLICATION, `U+2062` INVISIBLE TIMES, `U+2063` INVISIBLE SEPARATOR и даже некоторые дефисы, такие как мягкий дефис (`U+00AD`), дефис слога (`U+00СA`) и т. д).

А вот когда мы подбираемся к литералам, особенно к строковым, то понимаем, что раздолье наступает такое, что нас уже не остановить. Мы можем использовать фактически любой символ из UCS, а это 1,114,112 кодовых позиций, если брать суммарно. Здесь конечно можно возразить и сразу же вычесть верхние и нижние суррогаты (2,048 кодовых позиций), а там ещё порассуждать над целесообразностью учёта символов, которые помечены, как `<not a character>`, а также те, которые зарезервированы под частное использование. Хотя мы можем спокойно использовать любой codepoint в своих личных целях, даже те, которые выделены под суррогаты.

Так какую же величину имеет наш алфавит? 1,114,112 символов (если охватывать всё кодовое пространство Unicode)? 1,112,064, если вычесть из этого количества суррогаты? Или и вовсе 143,924 символа, если брать в расчёт исключительно символы, которые имеют графическое представление, а также форматирующие и управляющие. И то, это будет справедливо для Unicode 13.0. А если учитывать тот факт, что класс java.lang.Character в Java SE 14 поддерживает лишь версию Unicode 12.1, то правильно ли говорить, что в нашем распоряжении ещё меньше символов, а точнее 137,994 (именно столько символов однозначно определено в этой версии Unicode)? Этот вопрос всегда волновал, так как неопределённость мне не очень нравится и всегда хочется дать чёткий ответ на поставленный вопрос. Лично я считаю, что мы можем использовать абсолютно все кодовые позиции так, как посчитаем нужным (такая возможность есть, но так лучше не делать). Именно поэтому, если мы больше говорим о теории, то мне кажется, что мы упираемся лишь в ограничения самого стандарта и кодировки UTF-16. Согласны со мной? Или я всё-таки не совсем верно рассуждаю и 1,114,112 символов далеки от истины? Интересно Ваше мнение по данному вопросу! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверно вы понимаете, согласно [спецификации Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) идентификаторы могут быть любыми Unicode символами (ну кроме специально зарезервированных)

В принципе, можно написать примерно так:

```
int мояПеременная=1;
```

Правда в компиляторе надо указать кодировку, типа:

```
javac -encoding <code>
```

**Update**

Если честно, мне как все равно, сколько символов составляет алфавит Java: 125 тыс или 129 тыс. или там миллион. Это же типичная проблема точного определения, как только вы озаботитесь точным определением, границы сразу же начинают размываться.

Простой вопрос - сколько букв в русском алфавите? 33? Вы уверены? Может все таки 32, где `е` и `ё` - разные варианты одной буквы `е`, а как насчет `й`?

То же самое и здесь. Уверен, что 99.9% Java программистов успешно живут используя для Java строго только латинский алфавит из набора `alpha-numeric` и абсолютно счастливы.

Понимаю, что есть Хомский, есть философия и т.д., но я бы таки призвал слишком далеко не улетать и остаться в рамках `latin alphanumeric`

Comment: Что касается идентификаторов, то это очевидно, я знаю все эти нюансы. Разумеется, что не любой символ можно использовать в качестве составной части корректного идентификатора в языке программирования Java. Как и писал в теле вопроса, в Java SE 14 таких символов насчитывается 129,123. Именно такое количество символов мы можем использовать при составлении наших идентификаторов, при условии, что речь идёт не о начальном символе. Что же касается начального символа, с которого может начинаться идентификатор, то общее количество возможных вариантов уже чуть меньше, а точнее 125,951 символ.

Comment: Да и сам вопрос был не столько об идентификаторах, так как с ними действительно всё понятно, а об общем количестве символов, которые составляют алфавит языка программирования Java. Сама суть вопроса была подробно расписана в последнем абзаце.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Что касается минимального набора символов, который может удовлетворить все наши потребности, то полностью с Вами согласен! Фактически, чтобы написать абсолютно любую программу, нам было бы достаточно не более 18-ти символов. `u`, `\ ` и набор шестнадцатеричных цифр (для значений `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` и `f` вполне достаточно строчного варианта представления, прописные аналоги можно упустить). Стоит заметить, что никто не будет писать программы с использованием одних лишь управляющих Unicode-последовательностей, но уже сам факт того, что это возможно, заставляет задуматься.

Comment: Вы не задумывались, что можно вообще то и битами `0/1` - то есть теоретически можно обойтись и 2-мя символами

Comment: Точно-точно! Только это уже совсем экстремальный вариант программирования. Для этого достаточно установить какой-нибудь удобный Hex-редактор и вручную менять двоичное представление для каждого байта. В этом случае нам будет достаточно двух клавиш на клавиатуре. Вы совершенно правы! :)

Answer (score 1):

Распишу и своё собственное видение по данному вопросу. Немного покумекал и судя по всему добрался до истины.

Итак, чтобы полностью вникнуть в этот вопрос, необходимо ещё раз обратиться к теории. Если рассматривать язык программирования Java с точки зрения лексической структуры, то мы можем выделить 5 основных видов токенов, которые являются входными элементами. Именно из последовательности этих входных элементов и состоит вся наша программа, а сами элементы представляют собой основу лексической грамматики языка и в то же время выступают в роли терминальных символов синтаксической грамматики. Всю информацию можно найти в соответствующем разделе [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html), а я лишь приведу небольшую сноску.

> The input characters and line terminators that result from escape
>   processing (§3.3) and then input line recognition (§3.4) are reduced
>   to a sequence of input elements.

```
Input: 
  {InputElement} [Sub]
InputElement:
  WhiteSpace 
  Comment 
  Token   
Token:
  Identifier
  Keyword 
  Literal 
  Separator 
  Operator
Sub: 
  the ASCII SUB character, also known as "control-Z"
```

Таким образом, мы можем видеть, что сколь-нибудь значащими входными элементами являются лишь токены, так как пробельные символы (в том числе и разделители строк, которые с точки зрения спецификации также относятся к пробельным символам) и комментарии полностью игнорируются компилятором в процессе генерации байт-кода. 
Давайте взглянем на ещё одну базовую продукцию и немного ознакомимся с алгоритмом трансляции символов во входном потоке.

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first
>   recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII
>   characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code
>   unit (§3.1) for the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other
>   characters unchanged. Representing supplementary characters requires
>   two consecutive Unicode escapes. This translation step results in a
>   sequence of Unicode input characters.

```
UnicodeInputCharacter:
  UnicodeEscape
  RawInputCharacter
UnicodeEscape:
  \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
UnicodeMarker:
  u {u}
HexDigit:
  (one of)
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F
RawInputCharacter:
  any Unicode character
```

Здесь необходимо обратить внимание на то, что наши Unicode-символы, которые и являются основной составляющей входных элементов, формирующихся после отбрасывания пробельных символов и комментариев, также проходят через процесс трансляции, если они были заданы при помощи управляющих последовательностей Unicode. Но здесь всё достаточно просто и очевидно, поэтому остановимся на необработанных входных символах, которые и интересуют нас больше всего. Именно из этой продукции становится понятно, что мы можем использовать в качестве этих символов "любые Unicode-символы".

Но вернёмся к нашим токенам, чтобы понять, какое количество Unicode-символов мы могли бы использовать для каждого отдельного вида наших терминальных символов синтаксической грамматики. Мы могли бы написать нашу программу при помощи одних лишь управляющих последовательностей Unicode, что могло бы сократить набор используемых символов до такой степени, что он был бы меньше, чем тот набор, который предлагает нам ASCII. Но, как не крути, все управляющие последовательности всё равно проходят через процесс трансляции и мы получаем на выходе конкретный Unicode-символ (может быть в пределах ASCII, так и далеко за его границами). Если говорить о ключевых словах, операторах и разделителях, то перечень этих токенов жёстко установлен спецификацией и мы никоим образом не можем его расширять. Соответственно, мы уже можем прикинуть, сколько уникальных символов нам могло бы понадобиться для записи каждого из них. Пока ничего сложного нет, так как мы не вышли даже за пределы ASCII. Что касается идентификаторов, то тут всё зависит от версии платформы Java SE, которую мы используем. Количество уникальных Unicode-символов, которые мы можем использовать при составлении наших идентификаторов постоянно растёт и составляет 129,123 символа для Java SE 14 (поддерживаются символы описанные в стандарте Unicode 12.1), если символ просто является частью идентификатора, но не начинается с него. И 125,951 символ, которым мы можем начинать наши идентификаторы. Проверить всё это можно при помощи соответствующих методов класса java.lang.Character. Очевидным является тот факт, что мы не можем использовать в качестве идентификаторов ключевые слова (в том числе ограниченные ключевые слова в процессе описания модуля), разделители и операторы, а также литералы логического типа и null.

Остаются только литералы (здесь пойдёт речь именно о строковых литералах). И тут мы подходим к интересным рассуждениям. Предположим, что мы активно используем плоскости Unicode, которые выделены для частного использования. Может же быть такое? Конечно же может! На практике это нереально представить, но условимся, что мы полностью использовали пространство 15 и 16 плоскости для своих целей (а также область для частного использования из BMP). У нас даже есть свой уникальный шрифт, в котором у нас отрисованы все те абстрактные символы, которые мы используем в этих плоскостях! А что нам мешает уже сейчас использовать все остальные плоскости, которые зарезервированы на будущее? Может быть это не совсем правильно с точки зрения стандарта, но мы можем использовать абсолютно любую кодовую позицию для представления какого-то своего символа. Мы можем даже использовать те кодовые позиции, которые помечены, как `<not a character>`, а верхние и нижние суррогаты считать отдельными символами, если они не стоят последовательно друг за другом в потоке и не представляют собой суррогатную пару. Это не совсем корректно с точки зрения стандарта и какого-то здравого смысла, но у компилятора это никаких вопросов не вызовет. Он всё это с удовольствием "скушает" и даже не подавится. Суть в том, что строки в языке программирования Java представляются при помощи 16-битных code unit'ов (The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding), они же UTF-16 code units. То бишь, это 1 или 2 code unit'a, которые мы можем использовать для представления конкретного символа. Что же касается кодировки UTF-16, то набор символов, которые можно представить при помощи этого формата представления Unicode, полностью соответствует предельному размеру UCS, то бишь, 1,114,112 символов.

В принципе, это и есть весь наш алфавит, который мы можем использовать как угодно. Если предположить, что мы будем использовать все кодовые позиции в каких-то своих целях, а это теоритически возможно, то это единственный предел, в который мы реально упираемся. Таким образом, я считаю, что под фразой `any Unicode character`, мы можем понимать любой абстрактный символ из 1,114,112 возможных (весь набор UCS).